# Where are the jpg files in OpenCV sample camera_calibration

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration

The "camera_calibration" is a sample of calib3d in OpenCV. In this folder, a file named "VID5.xml" listing the images for running. But I could not find these jpg files in OpenCV source.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those images are not shipped with OpenCV. You need to take a few snapshot of the board with your camera.

---

The file [VID5.xml](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/05b15943d6a42c99e5f921b7dbaa8323f3c042c6/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/calib3d/camera_calibration/VID5.xml) is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
<images>
images/CameraCalibraation/VID5/xx1.jpg
images/CameraCalibraation/VID5/xx2.jpg
images/CameraCalibraation/VID5/xx3.jpg
images/CameraCalibraation/VID5/xx4.jpg
images/CameraCalibraation/VID5/xx5.jpg
images/CameraCalibraation/VID5/xx6.jpg
images/CameraCalibraation/VID5/xx7.jpg
images/CameraCalibraation/VID5/xx8.jpg
</images>
</opencv_storage>
```

As explained in the [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d4/d94/tutorial_camera_calibration.html):

> In the configuration file you may choose to use camera as an input, a video file or an image list. **If you opt for the last one, you will need to create a configuration file where you enumerate the images to use.**

and

> I've used an AXIS IP camera to create a **couple of snapshots of the board and saved it into VID5 directory.**

---

Alternatively, for a quick test you can use the images the images `right01.jpg, ..., right14.jpg`, or `left01.jpg, ..., left14.jpg` from the [samples/data](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/05b15943d6a42c99e5f921b7dbaa8323f3c042c6/samples/data) directory inside the *source* folder.